# expandable list view through android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

please tell me how to work with expandable list view give some examples.If i click or select any one of the value in the content of the list view that value should present inside the edit text box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find working example of the expandable list view by following links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

[refer](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html) this example for expandable list view. In this example the checkboxs values are persist...you can do the same way with edit text value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method,

public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)

of ExpandableListView to get the child and group position of the row, and fill the EditText.